# Unity 3d Text (changing 3d text)

Tags: unity-game-engine

how do I change 3d text to a float or integer, I know how to change UI text but I'm not sure how to change 3d text using text mesh pro.
The usual code I use to change UI text is this

```
public Text rotationText;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    rotationText.text = roattion.ToString();
}
```

Comment: So instead of `UI.Text` use a `TMP_Text`?

Answer (score 0):

You get a refence to the 3dtext and change as you need.

```
using TMPro; 

....
    [SerializeField] TMP_Text textToChange;
private int roattion = 12;

void Start()
{
    textToChange.text = "some text: "+roattion.ToString();
}
```